# control is not going through if statement

Tags: java, awt

I've a database named country which contains 3 table country(country_name), state(state_name,country_name), city(city_name,state_name)  and i want to add ountry, state and city by this frame but the control is not going through the 2nd if statement under actionPerformed()

[here is the image of console and frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXhay.png)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Admin extends Frame implements ActionListener
{
    MenuBar mb;
    Menu edit;
    MenuItem country,state,city;
    Label l1,l2,l3,l4,l5;
    TextField t1,t2,t3;
    Button b1,b2,b3;
    Choice ch1,ch2;
    String str1,str2,str3,str4;
    Connection con;
    PreparedStatement ps;
    ResultSet rs;

    public Admin()
    {
        super("Admin");

        setLayout(null);
        setSize(700,700);
        mb=new MenuBar();
        edit=new Menu("Edit");
        country=new MenuItem("Add Country");
        state=new MenuItem("Add State");
        city=new MenuItem("Add City");
        edit.add(country);
        edit.add(state);
        edit.add(city);
        mb.add(edit);

        country.addActionListener(this);
        state.addActionListener(this);
        city.addActionListener(this);
        setMenuBar(mb);
        setVisible(true);
        try
        {
            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
                            con=DriverManager.getConnection
 ("jdbc:ucanaccess://D:/java/country.mdb");
        }
        catch(Exception e){}
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {
        if(ae.getSource()==country){
            removeAll();
            l1=new Label("Country Name");
            t1=new TextField(20);
            b1=new Button("Update");
            l1.setBounds(150,100,100,25);
            t1.setBounds(290,100,100,25);
            b1.setBounds(280,140,70,25);

            add(l1);
            add(t1);
            add(b1);
            b1.addActionListener(this);
            setVisible(true);
            //System.out.println("Outside of if");

           if(ae.getSource()==b1){
                System.out.println("Inside of if");
                try
                {
                    ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into country
   (country_name) values('"+t1.getText()+"')");
                    ps.executeUpdate();

                }   
                catch(Exception e){}
            }
            //Add_country ob=new Add_country();
            //ob.setVisible(true);
        }
        else if(ae.getSource()==state){
            removeAll();
            l2=new Label("Select Country");
            ch1=new Choice();
            l3=new Label("Add State");
            t2=new TextField();
            b2=new Button("Update");

            l2.setBounds(150,100,100,25);
            ch1.setBounds(290,100,100,25);
            l3.setBounds(150,160,100,25);
            t2.setBounds(290,160,100,25);
            b2.setBounds(280,200,70,25);

            add(l2);
            add(ch1);
            add(l3);
            add(t2);
            add(b2);
            b2.addActionListener(this);
            setVisible(true);

            try
            {
                ps=con.prepareStatement("select country_name from country");
                rs=ps.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    str1=rs.getString("country_name");
                    ch1.addItem(""+str1);
                }
                if(ae.getSource()==b2){
                    System.out.println("sdfghjk");
                    str2=ch1.getSelectedItem();
                    ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into state
   (state_name,country_name) values('"+t2.getText()+"','"+str2+"')");
                    ps.executeUpdate();


                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
            //Add_state obj=new Add_state();
            //obj.setVisible(true);
        }
        else if(ae.getSource()==city){
            removeAll();
            l4=new Label("Select State");
            ch2=new Choice();
            l5=new Label("Add City");
            t3=new TextField();
            b3=new Button("Update");

            l4.setBounds(150,100,100,25);
            ch2.setBounds(290,100,100,25);
            l5.setBounds(150,160,100,25);
            t3.setBounds(290,160,100,25);
            b3.setBounds(280,200,70,25);

            add(l4);
            add(ch2);
            add(l5);
            add(t3);
            add(b3);
            b3.addActionListener(this);
            setVisible(true);
            try
            {
                ps=con.prepareStatement("select state_name from state");
                rs=ps.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next())
                {
                    str3=rs.getString("state_name");
                    ch2.addItem(""+str3);
                }

                if(ae.getSource()==b3){
                    System.out.println("sdfghjk");
                    str4=ch2.getSelectedItem();
                    ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into city
   (city_name,state_name) values('"+t3.getText()+"','"+str4+"')");
                    ps.executeUpdate();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e){}
            //Add_city obj=new Add_city();
            //obj.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String s[])
    {
        Admin ob=new Admin();
    }
}
```

Comment: did you check if the == works with comparing MenuItem objects?

Comment: first if statement is executing but the nested if is not working

Comment: You can't compare Objects using the == operator. You have to use the equals()-method. Therefor the "ae.getSource()==state"-comparison won't ever show up with the expected result.

Comment: if statements for  menuItems are working fine but if under those for buttons(b1,b2,b3) are not working

Comment: When you step through the code in your debugger, what is the `ae.getActionCommand()` ?  BTW Don't throw away exception especially in a program which isn't working.

Comment: Peter is right, why in the world would you ignore exceptions when you are clearly having problems with your code. As far as I'm concerned, it's an Exception that is causing your problem. Wherever you have: `catch(Exception e){}`  replace with `catch(Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }` and post the Stack Trace you are getting when you run your code within your original post.

Comment: @DevilsHnd still nothing happened the frame is opening but insertion is not happening and no Stack Trace

Comment: And what happens when you debug your code, as in stepping through it with your debugger. Can you see why it is skipping past your nested **if** code block?

Comment: @DevilsHnd Actually I'm a beginner and I am using Sublime Text and I don't know how to debug a program(Sorry)

Comment: You can't have an event which is generated by both `country` AND `b1` at the same time, it's impossible

Comment: @MadProgrammer as you've mentioned about ActionEvent can you please tell me how to use it in my program

Comment: When `actionPerformed` is called, it represents a single action, which is represented by `ActionEvent`, it's impossible for `ActionEvent` to represent more than one action, so `ae.getSource()==b1` CAN NOT be true when `ae.getSource()==country` is, it's just impossible

Answer (score 1):

This...

```
if(ae.getSource()==country){
    //...
    if(ae.getSource()==b1){
```

is impossible, you can't have an `ActionEvent` which is triggered by two different controls generate a single `actionPerformed` event (they'd occur one after the other)

## Observations

- Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify
- AWT is really out of date, people have more experience with Swing no days and even JavaFX
- You're not closing your (database) resources, which could led to issues with the database not been accessible. Have a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for a possible solution
- I'd also recommend [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to provide for better management of the components and views